# How to change a particular attribute value in Angular 2 / ionic 2?

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

So I have this `html` which dynamically creates cards using the `*ngFor`

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let numbers of [0,1,2,3]; let i = index">

    <ion-card-content>
      <ion-card-title clear>
           Card {{i}}
       </ion-card-title>
    </ion-card-content>


    <button ion-button block class="blockbutton" (click)="doSomething(i)">
      <ion-icon [name]="iconName" class="plussign"></ion-icon>
      <div> Join Room </div>
    </button>

</ion-card>
```

And this is in my `.ts`

```
export class FeedPage {
    iconName : string;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
     this.iconName  = 'add-circle';
    }
  }

public doSomething(item): void{
    console.log(item);
    this.iconName = 'checkmark-circle';
  }
```

So this code, on clicking the Block Button, turns all the icons of all the Block Buttons to to `checkmark-circle`

How do I change **only** that Particular Button's icon i.e. `[name]` attribute to `checkmark-circle`.

I've succeeded in retrieving the `index` for that element. But how do I modify only that Particular Button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have an array of `iconNames`.

```
  <ion-icon [name]="iconName[i]" class="plussign"></ion-icon>
```

In your component side:

```
public doSomething(item): void{
    console.log(item);
    this.iconName[item] = 'checkmark-circle';
    }
  }
```

You will have to set the entire array depending on the number of cards though.

```
iconNames:string[]=[];
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
        //loop through your card count and push initial value.
        iconNames.push(`add-circle`);


   }
```

Comment: Thank you. Got it to work. I just got started with Angular 2... But isn't this implementation just complicated ? All this was easier with jQuery, in which I would just do `$(this).attr('name','add-circle')`  , My question is, does Angular's implementation have any advantage ?

Comment: I would have had a single object containing a particular card details and set all info within the loop.. That way you wouldnt need a different loop to initialize icons..jQuery allows to handle DOM elements easily but it cant be used with Angular and its change detection..

Answer (score 0):

You should have different icon names for each items in the array.

First maintain an array of objects in your .ts like this:

```
private _array = [{"iconName" : "name1"},{"iconName" : "name2"}]; // And so on..
```

Now, in your .html:

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let numbers of _array let i = index">

    <ion-card-content>
       <ion-card-title clear>
           Card {{i}}
       </ion-card-title>
    </ion-card-content>


    <button ion-button block class="blockbutton" (click)="doSomething(numbers)">
      <ion-icon [name]="numbers.iconName" class="plussign"></ion-icon>
      <div> Join Room </div>
    </button>

</ion-card>
```

And doSomething() will become:

```
public doSomething(item): void{
    console.log(item);
    item.iconName = 'checkmark-circle';
}
```